# Condensing multiple if statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have this:

```
if(currentSlide !== 3) {
    $('#chapterBackground.intro').fadeOut(100);
}

if(currentSlide !== 4) {
    $('#chapterBackground.intro').fadeOut(100);
}
```

...and want to essentially say if currentSlide is neither 3 OR 4, then perform the fadeOut function.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? As written, the fadeout will occur on every slide because at least one of those tests will always be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((currentSlide !== 3) || (currentSlide !== 4))  {
    $('#chapterBackground.intro').fadeOut(100);
}
```

Apologies, edited.

Comment: Alternatively, it's literally the same as just `$('#chapterBackground.inro').fadeOut(100);` without any `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) operator within a single `if` condition:

```
if(currentSlide !==3 || currentSlide !==4) {
    $('#chapterBackground.intro').fadeOut(100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
if(currentSlide !== 3 || currentSlide !== 4) {
    $('#chapterBackground.intro').fadeOut(100);
}
```

The `||` means "OR". For "AND" you would use the `&&` operator ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(currentSlide !== 3 || currentSlide !== 4) {
    $('#chapterBackground.intro').fadeOut(100);
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `==` and `!=` whenever possible (i.e. almost 100% of the time).

Comment: You can also simplify the code by removing the inner parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

And here goes mine:

```
if ( currentSlide + 1 >> 1 != 1 )
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

Just one of many options:

```
currentSlide = 3;

//The number would match the slide you want the transition to occur at
//So at slide 3 I want the intro to fade out
var slideIndexes = {
        3 : function() { $('#chapterBackground.intro').fadeOut(100); },
        16 : function() { $('#chapterBackground.presentation').fadeOut(100); },
        20 : function () { $('#chapterBackground.credits').fadeOut(100); }
};

if (slideIndexes[currentSlide]) slideIndexes[currentSlide]();
```

And a beautiful [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/HU9dH/) to accompany this code.